# Missing sObjects on Tooling API

Tags: sobject, tooling-api

I was trying to query some entries using the Tooling API to get the SymbolTable from ApexClass/ApexTrigger. To do this I need to use the following sObjects (from Tooling API):

- ApexClass;
- ApexClassMember;
- ApexTrigger;
- ApexTriggerMember;
- MetadataContainer;
- ContainerAsyncRequest.

However, when I query ApexTrigger I got: `[{"message":"sObject type 'ApexTrigger' is not supported.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]`. Using the Workbench I listed all sObjects from Tooling API and I got this:
[image]

As we can see, the ApexClass is listed (and I can query it), but the ApexTrigger isn't (and the others aren't either).

There is any way to enable or make appear the others sObjects on Tooling API? To be able to use them later.

Comment: Thanks @identigral for your responses. After some digging in my profile permission we found that this issue was related to a missing System Permission named "View All Data". After we grant this, I was able to see those missing sObjects from Tooling API point of view.